# Fourier Series of periodic square wave centered at zero using complex exponentials

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

[image: Square Wave]

Hello I am trying to find the $D_n$ coefficient for the given square wave using complex exponentials.

$$D_n = \frac{1}{4}[\int_{1}^{3}(-1)e^{\frac{-jn \pi t}{2}}dt + \int_{3}^{5}(1)e^{\frac{-jn \pi t}{2}}dt ]$$
Afterward I get the following which is simplified to the best of my with skipping a couple of steps

$$D_n = \frac{1}{2jn \pi}[2e^{\frac{-3nj \pi}{2}} - e^{\frac{-nj \pi}{2}} - e^{\frac{-5nj \pi}{2}}]$$

I was wondering if this expression could be simplified further, thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: use $e^{nj\pi}=(-1)^n$ and $e^{2nj\pi}=1$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is the following correct $\frac{2}{n \pi}$ for odd integers and zero otherwise?

Comment: Looks right based on: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html